# I want to uninstall an angular-cli

Tags: angular

I used version 2.4 of angular 2.

This problem has occurred

（[Uncaught ReferenceError: __ng_jsonp____req0_finished is not defined at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053160/uncaught-referenceerror-ng-jsonp-req0-finished-is-not-defined-at)）

I decided to follow the instructions.

I want to change to version 2.3

`npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17 --save-dev`

I typed this command at the terminal.

The result is an error message

```
└─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17 
  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.7

  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
 @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4

  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY 
@angular/core@2.4.7

  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY 
@angular/platform-server@2.4.7

  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY 
@angular/tsc-wrapped@0.3.0

  ├── compression-webpack-plugin@0.3.2  (git://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git#7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54)
  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY 
rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY 
webpack@2.1.0-beta.25

  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY 
zone.js@0.6.26
```

I want to turn off the angular-cli.
I want to install angulacli 2.3 again.

Someone please tell me the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular-cli can be a little b*tch when it comes to uninstalling or updating. I had several problems when trying out other versions or changing stuff on it.

As Suren Srapyan suggested use

`npm unsintall -g angular-cli` when using the versions prior to (i think) `1.0.0-beta.28` and

`npm unsintall -g @angular/cli` for versions after that.

Also try to `npm cache clean` **BEFORE** installing another version as (as of the told b*tchy behaviour of the cli) it sometimes seems to lay eggs in the cache ruining the fun of updating it.